# How to add an array of string to an object in Parse Platform for Android?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, parse-server

So there is a `ParseObject.getList()` method and adding an ArrayList() to the object -

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
names.add("Charlie");   
user.addUnique("Names", names);
```

creates the following within the document -

```
"Names" : [
    [
        "Charlie"
    ]
]
```

but what I want is

```
"Names" : [
    "Charlie",
    "John",
    "Joseph"
]
```

Comment: `addAll` instead of addUnique ?

Comment: Thanks @IonutJ.Bejan, `addAll` worked.